# I am using request.post method of python for calling post method of API Developed in C#

Tags: c#, python, json, api, postman

I am using **requests.post** method of python for calling post method of API Developed in C#. While calling it via python I am getting an error, but when I used POSTMAN it's working without error.
I am getting the following error:

{'Status': False,
 'Message': ***'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'***,
 'Data': {'succeeded': False},
 'TotalRecords': 0}

So I have some doubts :

1. If C# API working fine while hitting from POSTMAN but not working with my Python Script. So is there any problem with my Python code?
2. Is it valid to use **requests.post** for calling C# API?
3. Is there any problem with JSON Format of Data that I am passing to C# API?

**Python Script:**

```
import requests

headers = {'Token': 'AnyRandomToken','Content-Type':'application/json'}
your_data = {'EmployeeId': 'XXXXXXXX'}

r = requests.post("URLForC#ApiCan'tShareOverHere", headers=headers, data=your_data).json()
```

Comment: The language that is used to develop an API does not relate to the response received from it in any way.

If it works fine with postman and not fine with requests, You probably have an error with your syntax.

Please post your raw request from postman to allow us to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get a solution.
I simply remove **content-type** variable from **header** and then hit the C# API, I get a valid response.

Comment: Well, that seems like a server side error, then, unless it is doesn't actually accept JSON data